# ps/2 port of the case doesn't work properly

Tags: windows-xp, ps2, ps2-keyboard

I'm going to install Win XP on my computer (I had win 7 but had some problem with installing the HP printer on it and so I decide to install XP because that printer seems to be installed properly on XP).
Now When I put the XP CD on the CD driver, it says press a ker to boot from CD and I press the Enter key, (now the keyboard works) after that, within installation time when that I should press Enter to install XP, this time the keyboard doesn't work.
My guess is that the ps/2 port of the case has problem (it's old and somewhat has been broad).
Now what is the solution in your point of view please?

My system manufacturer is "ECS" and the system model is "945pl-A".

PS: When I what to enter to BIOS, (on the top of second black and white screen it has been written that "Press shift-F10 to configure) and when I press these two I enter to an environment that seems to be the BIOS but it has very few options! I'm not sure is it BIOS, or how to go into BIOS in that motherboard.

Comment: It sounds like the install has switched to graphics mode when you think the enter key is not working (and you aren't using a mouse). Try using the tab key to see where the focus is before pressing enter.

Comment: You say when I'm prompted to press the Enter key (when it says r=repair, F3=quit and Enter for installing Windows) I should press Tab key instead of Enter key?

Comment: Not exactly. Many of the install prompts are graphical (I didn't remember XP in particular) and expect a mouse click. You can use just a keyboard but sometimes the focus isn't where you expect it so the enter key doesn't go where you expect. The tab key will move the focus to the next "button" or focus area and you can see it changing then. In your description it seemed to me that you might not have a mouse.

Comment: I do have mouse, it's trivial. But you apparetly have forgotten the way of installing XP because it does not support in primary steps of installation. I appreciate your helps but I think you didn't notice to my question properly.

Comment: I read it more than once, but you're welcome.